# Geometry Calculation in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geometry

I'm trying to calculate the area of some census tracts in qgis
I go to vector -> geometry tools -> export/add geometry columns

in the resulting dialog, I calculate using project CRS. What comes out in the attribute table is something like 0.000018 or 0.0000152. I don't know what units these are in; most other information on the internet seems to say that this issue is a map projection issue.

For the record, the current map project is NAD83 EPSG 4269

I do not know what unit this is in. If I knew the unit, it would be pretty trivial to add a new 'calculating' column to the attribute table to determine the area in language I can understand.

Comment: They're in square degrees, so not easy to just recalculate them into something useful. You'll need to reproject the data, see this [Q & A](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144004/calculate-area-intersected-areas-problem/144016#144016).